# How to find moving difference with smallest number

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to find moving smallest value like excel if else condition in redshift sql.

This is my query.

```
SELECT *,
  MIN(avg_ttm) OVER (PARTITION BY ASIN ORDER BY ASIN,
  CASE WHEN ageband_on_cost_acquisition_date = 'Current' THEN 1 
    WHEN ageband_on_cost_acquisition_date = '[31-60]' THEN 2 
    WHEN ageband_on_cost_acquisition_date = '[61-90]' THEN 3 
    WHEN ageband_on_cost_acquisition_date = '[91-120]' THEN 4 
    WHEN ageband_on_cost_acquisition_date = '[121-150]' THEN 5 
    WHEN ageband_on_cost_acquisition_date = '[151-180]' THEN 6 
    WHEN ageband_on_cost_acquisition_date = '[181-270]' THEN 7 
    WHEN ageband_on_cost_acquisition_date = '[271-360]' THEN 8 
    WHEN ageband_on_cost_acquisition_date = 'Over 360' THEN 9 
    END ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS proposed_rate
FROM ccogs;
```

[image]

You can get the data set link and my practiced queries in the below link

https://dbfiddle.uk/89wf0tPk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to unbound the window function:

```
select *,       MIN(avg_ttm) OVER (PARTITION BY ASIN order by CASE
             WHEN ageband_on_cost_acquisition_date = 'Current' THEN 1
             WHEN ageband_on_cost_acquisition_date = '[31-60]' THEN 2
             WHEN ageband_on_cost_acquisition_date = '[61-90]' THEN 3
             WHEN ageband_on_cost_acquisition_date = '[91-120]' THEN 4
             WHEN ageband_on_cost_acquisition_date = '[121-150]' THEN 5
             WHEN ageband_on_cost_acquisition_date = '[151-180]' THEN 6
             WHEN ageband_on_cost_acquisition_date = '[181-270]' THEN 7
             WHEN ageband_on_cost_acquisition_date = '[271-360]' THEN 8
             WHEN ageband_on_cost_acquisition_date = 'Over 360' THEN 9
           END
           rows between unbounded preceding and current row ) AS proposed_rate from ccogs;
```

In Excel you are referencing the output of the previous row's calculation which is recursive (slow).  By just finding the MIN() over all previous rows you do the same thing.

Also you don't need to have ASIM in the order by clause as it is the partition by value so it is constant within each partition.